# A Ruby module to simulate key press and key released events?

Tags: ruby, simulation, keypress, keyrelease

I want to create a application that simulates various users but I need this "ghost" users to type on the keyboard, how to I simulate a keypress and keyrealease events on Ruby?

Comment: In which environment are you planing on using this application? Browser? Desktop?

Comment: In Safari on MacOS X, I found a solution using a module called 'appscript', there is a method for simulate key events, i.e. Appscript.app('System Events').keystroke(' '); simulates a spacebar click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java has a class called Robot(I think) which simulates stuff like that.You could use JRuby to invoke that. I ever had some testscript somewhere,I'll post it when i find it..but I remember it was really dead simple to do that with that class,you even could move the cursor around ,really funny tough.